# How to apply shell extension(icon overlays) and context menu in OS X application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

As I am currently working on `OS X application`. I want the functionality like dropbox have as per bellow screen short (There is right image beside of directory and file name) And (when I right click on file it will show me option to open file with `MyApplication` as like dropbox).
[image]

[image]

Can you please help for this. Any link/blog/tutorials should be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, I am trying this for long time & I could not get success. So I need some help come out from this situation. Please Do not mark it as close. I am struck at somewhere asking for help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with the new "Finder Sync" Framework.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html

Greetings
Florian